# What are the parameters to tf.GradientTape()'s __exit__ function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, oop, with-statement, automatic-differentiation

According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) for `tf.GradientTape`, its `__exit__()` method takes three positional arguments: `typ, value, traceback`.

**What exactly are these parameters?**

How does the `with` statement infer them?

What values should I give them in the code below (where I'm *not* using a `with` statement):

```
x = tf.Variable(5)

gt = tf.GradientTape()
gt.__enter__()
y = x ** 2
gt.__exit__(typ = __, value = __, traceback = __)
```

Comment: This is documented in the [docs for `__exit__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__), as well as the [original `with` PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).